# Emptyset is a power set of .....what?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I got this question that asks whether or not $\emptyset$ is a power set of a set.

I have the answer, which is yes, but I can't remember the reason. Any help are welcome!

Comment: The power set always contains $\emptyset$, so the power set can't be empty.

Comment: The *power-set* is the set of **all** subsets of a set. $\emptyset$ is subset of **every** set. Thus, the power-set of a set $A$ will have at least one element : $\emptyset$ and so it cannot be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong. The powerset of empty set is *not* an empty set; it is a single-element set, and its only element is an empty set: $$P(\{\}) = \{\,\{\}\,\}$$ This relates also to the cardinalities: $$|P(A)| = 2^{|A|}$$ so if $A=\{\}$ and $|A|=0$ then $|P(A)|=2^0=1$, hence the powerset has an item — is not empty.

Comment: So my main question was whether or not ∅ is a power set of a set?? That what i want to know

Comment: You got the answer in comments by [Carl Heckman](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460719/emptyset-is-a-power-set-of-what/1460733#comment2974618_1460719) and by [Mauro ALLEGRANZA](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460719/emptyset-is-a-power-set-of-what/1460733#comment2974620_1460719). Read them. The answer is: NO, a powerset always has at least one item, so it can not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if the empty set were the power set of some set A, what would be the subsets of A? How many would there be?